# Is it possible to interrupt NSURLSessionDownloadTask after getting headers, before start getting data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, networking

I have `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`, loading large file. Trying to check if it was modified since the specific timestamp on the server. Server (over which I have no control) doesnt seem to support `If-Modified-Since` header.

I'd like to get Modification Date header, compare it with my value, and if its older - do not download. Is it possible to do that with `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` or I have to use `NSURLSessionDateTask` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following `delegate` method of `NSURLSession`

```
@protocol NSURLSessionDataDelegate <NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>
@optional
/* The task has received a response and no further messages will be
 * received until the completion block is called. The disposition
 * allows you to cancel a request or to turn a data task into a
 * download task. This delegate message is optional - if you do not
 * implement it, you can get the response as a property of the task.
 *
 * This method will not be called for background upload tasks (which cannot be converted to download tasks).
 */
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
                                 didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                                  completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler;
```

and the following cancelling method of `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`

```
@interface NSURLSessionDownloadTask : NSURLSessionTask

    /* Cancel the download (and calls the superclass -cancel).  If
     * conditions will allow for resuming the download in the future, the
     * callback will be called with an opaque data blob, which may be used
     * with -downloadTaskWithResumeData: to attempt to resume the download.
     * If resume data cannot be created, the completion handler will be
     * called with nil resumeData.
     */
    - (void)cancelByProducingResumeData:(void (^)(NSData * _Nullable resumeData))completionHandler;
```

The mentioned delegate method is called right after complete response header has been received, so you can verify corresponding fields and make decision either to continue or to cancel.